# Prometheus with blackbox exporter http status code of 0

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, grafana-variable, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

In Prometheus with black box exporter for website monitoring getting http status code of 0 (zero) in the some datapoints.
Any comments please

tried to Corelated "https 0" for any actaull error/issue with infra & at the same time instances dint found any issues.

Comment: And what does other `probe_...` metrics show? For example, `probe_success` and `probe_duration_seconds`?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, a status code `0` with an HTTP probe means that an error has occurred before the blackbox exporter has received an answer with the actual status code. Most often this is either a "connection timeout" or "connection refused" error. You can find out what it is by making a request like this:

```bash
curl 'http://my.blackbox.exporter:9115/probe?target=example.com&module=http_2xx&debug=true'
```

... and then checking the logs of the exporter.